# How to add multiple series in highcharts synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I tried to add multiple series in highcharts synchronously, but the response time is very slow. It took almost 3-5 seconds to display the charts. Here is part of the code.

```
   while(chart.series.length>0){
                chart.series[0].remove(true);
                    }
            chart.addSeries(series1);
                chart.addSeries(series2);
                chart.addSeries(series3);
                chart.addSeries(series4);
                chart.addSeries(series5);
```

When I remain only one addSeries command, it response immediately, so I realized it may be the problem of add multiple series in highcharts synchronously.
Not so good at highcharts, so is there anyone could help me about this? Or maybe there is another way to do this, I am much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, add the series ***asynchronously***. there are very few times you want (and need) to make synchronous requests. Last thing you want is your UI to get locked up. Out of curiosity, how much data is in each series? You can find a good amount online regarding [highcharts optimization](http://highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series)

Comment: There are almost 400 data in each series, what I want is showing 5 lines by each request. So I need to add Series 5 times each time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`addSeries` accept `redraw` as second parameter.
So you can call it with it set to false and then the last one as true, which is the default.

```
var series = [ series1, series2, series3, series4 ],
    i = 0;

for( ; i < 4; i++ ) {
    chart.addSeries( series[i], false );
}

chart.addSeries(series5);
```

You can do the same to remove:

```
while( chart.series.length > 1 ){
    chart.series[0].remove( false );
}

chart.series[0].remove();
```